# Why does disabling a windows network adapter make an HTTP request to Akamai?

Tags: windows, networking

While setting up my `iptables`, I've noticed that when disabling a network adapter (at least in Windows 2012 Server), HTTP and HTTPS requests are made to various Akamai-owned addresses.  I can't think why.

I haven't had a closer look at the payload with Fiddler or anything, but does anyone know what these requests are for?  Seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: Does the server in question have the `Akamai NetSession Interface` service installed?

Comment: See what's in the requests, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect this is network location awareness: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Basically, Windows is making HTTP requests to verify it still has a connection to the internet.

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably right, was thinking it might be NLA after looking at it.  I'll investigate the packets, though alot of them are HTTPS.

Comment: See also NCSI...